# How to generate an entity from another entity JPA - Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have a spring boot JPA project with an entity called Customers and another one CustomerReports

```
@Entity
public class Customers {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private int id;
        private String Name;    
        @JsonIgnore
        @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
        private Reports reports;

//getter and setters..etc
}
```

```
@Entity
public class CustomerReports {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    private BigDecimal monthlyPayment;
    //done
    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "reports")
    private Customers customers;

//constructors, getters...etc.
}
```

I want whenever I insert a Customer, a report to also be generated for that customer. The column "monthlyPayment" in reports is also generated through a reference from another table so I don't want to insert those columns manually if that makes sense.

Is there a way to do that? I'm not sure what to google so it would be great if anyone can give me an idea

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question properly, you can derive `CustomerReports` entity based on `Customers` via simple java utility method & then call `save` if you are using `jparepository` :

```
    CustomerReports customerReports=reportUtil(customerEntity);
    jpaRepository.save(customerEntity);
    jpaRepository.save(customerReports);
    ...
     
    private CustomerReports reportUtil(Customers customerEntity){
    /*Derive values for CustomerReports based on Customers & return*/ 
   
}
```

Or if you don't want to do by this way then check if your underlying database support `triggers` which you can use for inserting data into `CustomerReports` while doing insert to `Customers`